# Creating delay with a while loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, delay, simulink

As a student I am currently working on a Matlab Simulink project. I am quite new to using Matlab/Simulink (few weeks).

I want to implement and run a Matlab “.m” file with which I can open Simulink and start the simulation. The aim is to do a 24h Test with a load cell cut into 1h “pieces” and to save the data to different sheets of an excel file each hour. So my simulation runs for 1h, stops and starts again, and so on. Through Matlab and a “for” loop I do the measures 24 times.
Between measuring steps I have to wait for simulink to finish its measures and saving the file in order for the Simulink window to be able to get closed by `close_system('Thesis_SerDatTransm_Simulink')`.

So I tried to implement the delay with a while loop and by checking if the measures I get fit into an array of the size bigger than 449 (I measure 449 values):

```
for k=0:1:24
    % Load Simulink
    load_system('Thesis_SerDatTransm_Simulink.slx')

    % Open Simulink
    open_system('Thesis_SerDatTransm_Simulink.slx')  

    % Start Simulation
    set_param('Thesis_SerDatTransm_Simulink', 'SimulationCommand', 'Start');

    % Save Data
    my_cell = sprintf('A%d',k);
    xlswrite('file.xlsx',y,my_cell)

    % Wait for Simulation
    while 1
        test=size(y)>=449;
       if (test)
         close_system('Thesis_SerDatTransm_Simulink')
         break
       end
    end
end
```

The Problem now is, that program gets stuck at the while loop. Simulink is started, but no simulation or data gathering is done.
So I wondered if anyone could check if something is wrong with my While loop, since the rest of the programm works all fine without the loop (but receiving an error message, that during the simulation, Simulink window can't be closed).
I know there is a way to create a delay with `waitfor`in matlab and create another `function` which I could call, but I couldn't figure out how to do this yet.

thanks

Regards

hohmchri

Comment: Your question mentions `449` values...but your code is testing for `499` values...which one is correct?

Comment: You only need to load and close your system once. Also, I don't think you need to use open_system if you already used load_system. So I think what you are trying to accomplish here is not needed, as the close_system function could actually be outside the For loop.

Comment: @gariepy, yes my bad. There is a typo. I changed it to 449 which is the correct number of values I want to check. I will do the test again tomorrow. I hope it works then. Thank you!

Comment: @m_power thank you for your reply. I will try this tomorrow. As said, I am quite new to using Matlab and programing in general. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this is to use the [sim](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/sim.html) function to run your model (not the sequence of `load_system`, `open_system` and `set_param` that you have).

`sim` will block the execution of m-code until the model completes executing.  Data can either be returned into the workspace (when used with no output arguments) or returned as an output from the call to `sim`. (And then you can write it to Excel as you've done.)

The only reason not to use `sim`, and perhaps use the commands you have, is if the model takes a long time to initialize, and you don't want to to open and close it every time through the loop.  However, even in this case your code isn't correct.  The `load_system` would be outside the loop; the `open_system` is not required; in your `while` loop you would *poll* the model's `SimulationStatus` property to see if it is still running (not the size of the `y` variable); and the `close_system` would be after the loop (as indicated by @m_power in one of the comments).

Comment: this worked perfectly! thanks! Finally I used `sim`. By that I am also avoiding to fill the code with lines I don't really need.

Answer (score 1):

As written you should use the matlab [pause](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pause.html) command. This stops your execution for X seconds.

You should also look to optimize your code as m_power states